# Moving a picture around slowly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I have a picture of an Air balloon.  I need it to fly around my page randomly (it is kind of small).  I need it only to fly in the top half of my page.  I found the following code:

```
$("#Friends").animate({ 
        top: "-=30px",
      }, duration );
```

But I'm not sure how I could loop it and have it go both on the x axis and the y axis.  Thanks if you can!  I do have jQuery enabled :)

Comment: This site is going to be awesome

Comment: lol, I will post an image of it soon, it is a project for my class but I want to add a little bit of pizazz :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS

```
#friends { position: absolute; }
```

Markup

```
<img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" 
id="friends"/>
```

JS

```
function moveit() {

    var newTop = Math.floor(Math.random()*350);
    var newLeft = Math.floor(Math.random()*1024);
    var newDuration = Math.floor(Math.random()*5000);

    $('#friends').animate({
      top: newTop,
      left: newLeft,
      }, newDuration, function() {
        moveit();
      });

}

$(document).ready(function() {
    moveit();
});
```

<s>Live demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/W69s6/embedded/result/</s>


More updated Live Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9cN4C/

*(old demo is obsolete and has a broken link, however the code is still correct so it is left for reference, not for demonstration)*

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw - Thank you for the edit. I seems jsfiddle have moved their logo png to a different directory.

Comment: Yes haha, that's why I used the google logo this time, it tends to be more ... permanent? Haha, good day:)

Answer (score 5):

How about something like this.... [LIVE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Jaybles/AudTa/)

**HTML**

```
<img src="http://www.birdsnways.com/imgs/blbd48rt.gif" id="picture" />
```

**CSS**

```
#picture{
    position:absolute;   
}
```

**JS**

```
doNextPoint();

function doNextPoint(){

    var maxX = $(window).width() - $('#picture').width();    
    var newX = rand(0, maxX);    
    var maxY = ($(window).height()/2) - $('#picture').height();
    var newY = rand(0, maxY);
    var speed  = rand (1000, 3000);

    $('#picture').animate({
        'top': newY + 'px',
        'left': newX + 'px' 
    }, speed, function(){
        doNextPoint();    
    });
}


function rand (min, max) {
     return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

Comment: Good job taking the task all the way.

Comment: +1 This is better than the currently accepted answer as it wisely takes screen sizes into account.

Comment: And I just realized this has been posted 5 minutes before I posted my answer and they look very similar! I feel bad :(

Answer (score 1):

You can stick that code into a named function, and then add that function as the callback parameter for the animation, so it will call itself again after it finishes.

```
var flying;
flying = function() {
    $("#Friends").animate({ 
        top: "-=30px",   // you'll need to change this
      },
      duration,
      flying
    );
}
flying();
```

As is, it will just keep flying upward because the animation is always set to go up by 30 px. You'll have to change the flying function to randomize the motions a bit. For more realism, save the previous movement, and just change it by a little (small acceleration) so it doesn't have very jerky motions.

Answer (score 0):

To loop it: use SetTimeout: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout

For the x-axis, use the CSS property left:  (top: will get you y-axis)

Comment: No - it is better to use `animate()` and call the function again once finished (http://jsfiddle.net/Jaybles/AudTa/). setTimeout is much less preferable.