# How to make an image move in a circular path using jquery?

Tags: jquery

Here i am trying to make an image move in a circular path but it is not moving in a circular path..I have tried like this [Moving a picture around slowly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915622/moving-a-picture-around-slowly)

CSS

```
#friends { position: absolute; }
```

Markup

```
<img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" 
id="friends"/>
```

JS

```
function moveit() {

    var newTop = Math.floor(Math.random()*350);
    var newLeft = Math.floor(Math.random()*1024);
    var newDuration = Math.floor(Math.random()*5000);

    $('#friends').animate({
      top: newTop,
      left: newLeft,
      }, newDuration, function() {
        moveit();
      });

}

$(document).ready(function() {
    moveit();
});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/W69s6/embedded/result/

Any Suggestion??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Another variant (based on [Div Moving in cycle rotation using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842789/div-moving-in-cycle-rotation-using-javascript)):

```
var t = 0;

function moveit() {
    t += 0.05;

    var r = 100;         // radius
    var xcenter = 100;   // center X position
    var ycenter = 100;   // center Y position

    var newLeft = Math.floor(xcenter + (r * Math.cos(t)));
    var newTop = Math.floor(ycenter + (r * Math.sin(t)));

    $('#friends').animate({
        top: newTop,
        left: newLeft,
    }, 1, function() {
        moveit();
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    moveit();
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/W69s6/20/

Comment: :Thanks..How to make more than one image revolving around a circle..one by one (back to back)

Comment: Try to call several `moveit` for different `div`s.

Comment: ya..How to stop the moving image on mouseover??

Comment: thanks man.working fine..But i have tried it with two images moving back to back..but one image is moving and the other one is not moving..can u make it in fiddle

Comment: I didn't get exactly what you're planning to have. Based on your description, it should be something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/W69s6/25/. Or like this: http://jsfiddle.net/W69s6/23/. You can optimise the code by yourself.

Comment: i need it like this http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/branches/labs/carousel/demo/dynamic.html

Comment: Oh, that's an absolutely different story. These images are not only rotating. However, why can't you exploit the script from the link?

Comment: no i dint want that exact thing...i want only two images rotating back to back in a circular path thats it

Answer (score 4):

Try this using Animate:

```
function animateCircle(id, speed, radius, startx, starty, phi) {  
    if (!phi) { phi = 0 };
    var int = 2 * (Math.PI) / speed;
    phi = (phi >= 2 * (Math.PI)) ? 0 : (phi + int);
    var $m = startx - radius * Math.cos(phi);
    var $n = starty - radius * Math.sin(phi);

    $("#friends").animate({
        marginLeft: $m + 'px',
        marginTop: $n + 'px'
      }, 1, function() { 
             animateCircle.call(this, id, speed, radius, startx, starty, phi) 
          }
    );

};
```

​
You can call the function for any `div` like this:

```
animateCircle('#friends', 100, 100, 400, 250);
```

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/W69s6/18/

**DEMO 2**: http://jsfiddle.net/W69s6/34/

Adapted from [here](http://tadhg.com/wp/2007/02/19/animating-circles-with-javascript/).

Comment: :Perfect..Thanks..How to make more than one image revolving around a circle..one by one means(back to back)

Comment: @bala3569 Just repeat the method for a different `div` with different variables. I'll refactor my code to promote reuse.

Comment: @bala3569 Done! That should be easier!

Comment: :No man not like this..Instead of 1 image i need two images which has to be moving in a circular path with certain amount of gap between those two images like this http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/branches/labs/carousel/demo/dynamic.html

Comment: @bala3569 So what's the problem? Just call the function I wrote with several images.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this awesome plugin [jQuery.path](http://weepy.github.com/jquery.path/) :)